# Slow system after running a KDE GUI application from a Debian Squeeze chroot

Tags: ubuntu, debian, kde, gui, chroot

I have a PC with Ubuntu 11.04 and a Debian Squeeze chroot installed in it.

As soon as I start any KDE application from within chroot (and installed there), e.g. Kompare for viewing `git diff` output, certain parts of the whole host system become slow to respond.

For example:

- The keyboard layout tray icon stops working, e.g. doesn't change layouts on click.
- The logout/restart/shutdown actions take a long time to actually start, e.g. 5 minutes or more, while doing `sudo reboot` is instantaneous.
- Open/save file dialogs are slow to open and close, and sometimes even unresponsive.

I've noticed that other non-KDE native applications like Eclipse, xli, meld don't have the same problems.

Does anyone have any ideas as to what might cause it?

Comment: are the plasma widgets locked? sometimes having them unlocked it slows everything down
 http://i.stack.imgur.com/TtW2K.jpg

Comment: I had them unlocked, so I tried locking them, but I didn't see any change though.